# How to use tkinter Canvas to create multiple text one time?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

For example:

```py
for i in range(10000):
   canvas.create_text(10*i,100,text='test',fill='red')
```

The main window get stuck when run this part. how can I avoid it when loading the text?

Comment: You can use `after()` to replace the for loop.

Comment: Could you detail how to use after()? many thanks!

Comment: Here's a little [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) on the `after()` widget method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `after()` to replace the for loop so that it won't block the tkinter `mainloop`:

```py
def show_text(n=0):
    # show 20 text in each iteration
    for i in range(20):
        y, x = divmod(n+i, 20)
        canvas.create_text(x*50, y*10, text='test', fill='red', anchor='nw')
    n += 20
    if n < 10000:
        canvas.after(1, show_text, n)

show_text() # start the after() loop
```

Comment: Much appreciate, thanks!